# HTTPS certificates are (almost) every week invalidated

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, keytool

Probably many of the people have the problem with the invalidation of the HTTPS certificates.

The daily routine is to reimport the certificate of the remote site using *JRE* `keytool` or `Keystore Explorer`.

What else could we do to automate the import process?

What to import the certificates during *JRE runtime*?

KI

Comment: This activity should be a one-time thing. Are you aware of any other application/event that replaces the `cacerts` or is your java being updated?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the invalidation of a certificate can happen on two occasions:

1. it is beyond the expiry date. That is easy to check and automatically builtin in the Java TrustManager
2. It is revoked before it would have expired. That means the CA no longer wants this
   certificate to be trusted and adds it to an Certificate Revocation List. In theory every client should not only check the certificate but also ask the CA whether it has been revoked in the meantime. Most browsers simply do not perform this check.

For reasons in 2) CAs prefer to sign certificates with short expiry dates, putting you into the situation you are in.

One way out of that is to not import the certificates in question but the intermediate CA certificate or even the root CA certificate. These certificates do not change that often but allow your client to automatically check if the certificate in question can be trusted.

Remaining is a chance that the remote certificate changes daily but does not have any intermediate or root CA => it is a self-signed certificate. In this case there are only two options you have: Import the certificate daily, or turn off certificate checks completely. Both methods no longer allow you to check whether the remote party is the expected remote party.